# Retrieve the userid of visitor of a application tab on a business page in Facebook

Tags: facebook

I have created a business page on facebook and added application to a tab.

I want to retrieve the uid of the users who visit the tab. I am using `$_POST['fb_sig_profile_user']`

But it give the page id not the uid.

Please help me on this.

Thanks

Pankaj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get the UID of the user viewing the tab unless they interact with it first:

> Application tabs behave like a hybrid of a canvas page and a profile box. A tab has the following properties:
>
> - It fetches data from its application servers.
> - It can load AJAX.
> - It doesn't know who the viewing user is when the user first visits the tab. Facebook sends the `fb_sig_user` and `fb_sig_profile_user` parameters, both containing the profile owner's user ID.
> - If a viewing user interacts with the tab (like submits a form, takes an action that causes an AJAX load of new content, or follows a relative URL that loads on the tab), that user's UID is sent to the application as the `fb_sig_user` parameter, the profile owner's user ID is sent as the `fb_sig_profile_user` parameter. The viewing user's session key is key is sent only if the user authorized the application.

(from http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Tabbed_Profile#Application%20Tab%20Behavior%20and%20Policies)

Comment: That wiki link seems to be dead. I look like Facebook has taken all that down.

Comment: I'd like to know the interaction counts for the instance or forever. As in, if I once interacted with a tab and I come back to it later does it still recognize me as a user or not?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so - for example (and if I remember correctly) active content such as Flash will only start up when a user interacts with the tab, and this applies each time they visit it.  So, I would expect that if you navigate away, then return, you would still have to have the user interact.  A word of advice though: Facebook are currently changing the formatting and layout of the application tabs, so things may be changing in the near future.